# Cycles render - rendering only text?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am downloaded the template form here> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zlK_F-29Sk , but if I render image or video i get this result: [image]

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you should increase the size of that light in the back under the light properties. It spreads the light out more.

Answer (score 1):

Set the render layer to Universal here :

[image]